# How to implement an HLS stream into hbbtv

Tags: javascript, html, http-live-streaming, hbbtv

The problem is implementing an HTTP Live Streaming (also known as HLS) in HbbTV
I cannot find a solution for it

I tried this for example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>HbbTV Stream</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function initApp() {
      var videoElement = document.createElement("video");
      videoElement.setAttribute("type", "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl");
      videoElement.setAttribute("src", "http.//example.com/test.m3u8");
      videoElement.setAttribute("data-fullscreen", "true");
      videoElement.setAttribute("data-pauseonexit", "true");
      videoElement.setAttribute("autoplay", "");
      videoElement.addEventListener("error", function(e) {
        console.log("Video error:", e);
      });
      document.body.appendChild(videoElement);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="initApp()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't help on older devices but if you are targeting HBBTV [2.0.3](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/102796/01.06.01_60/ts_102796v010601p.pdf) or later, devices should have support for [Media Source Extensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-media-source-20161117/), so you could try use a javascript-based player such as [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) or similar.